# how to send get request as if sent from browser

Tags: java, rest, browser, get, jersey-client

I'm trying to test several APIs and compare them.
For one of the rest services I can only get response when I type the request
in the browser.
When I send request from code (Java with Jersey) with the exact same URL I get 401 unauthorized.

As a workaround and also out of curiosity I want to have my java client send
requests as if it was a browser so I can easily test the responses.

this is purely for benchmarking... I'm aware that it's not a robust solution.

my code for get request:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class ClientTest
{

    @Test
    public void testGisGraphy()
    {

        String url = "http://services.gisgraphy.com/geocoding/geocode?address=89%20Rue%20Champoiseau%2C%20Tours&country=FR&format=JSON&postal=true";
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
        ClientResponse response =  webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
        String jsonString = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(jsonString.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked. 
Two headers, **"Accept-Encoding"** with value **"gzip"** and **"Accept-Language"** with any arbit value are required. Accept Encoding with value gzip is must. Accept Language with any arbit value is fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String url =
    "http://services.gisgraphy.com/geocoding/geocode?address=89%20Rue%20Champoiseau%2C%20Tours&country=FR&format=JSON&postal=true";
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
ClientResponse response =
    webResource
        .accept("application/json")
        .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip")
        .header("Accept-Language", "arbit text")
        .get(ClientResponse.class);
String jsonString = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(jsonString.toString());
}
```

I tried running it continuously. Following is what the response was:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Too much requests</title>
<style>
body { font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<table width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valigin="middle">
Your request can not be processed :
<ul>
<li>Are you a bot or do you use those webservices in a software ? you can only use the webservice in a browser</li>
<li>Do you reach the maximum number of requests / seconds allowed</li>
</ul>
<br/><br/>
Wait a little bit and resubmit your request
</br></br/>
 If you want to have better QOS and SLA, you can <a href="http://premium.gisgraphy.com/">subscribe to premium webservices</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Conclusion:-** On the server side they are making some checks so that only requests from browsers are serviced and rest are unauthorized.

Doing a trial and error, it seems request headers "Accept-Encoding" and "Accept-Language" are must in the request.

Answer (score -1):

You should specify user agent header

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work:

ClientResponse response =  webResource.accept("application/json").header("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36").get(ClientResponse.class);

(I copied the header from chrome debug mode)